# ioreg list multiple dext

Tags: macos, iokit, driverkit, macos-system-extension

I have written a system extension using DriverKit and USBDriverKit that seems to work well (running with developer mode on, SIP off, ... still waiting for entitlements).

When I plug my USB device and in terminal I type `ioreg | grep com.myinc.mydriver` I see one entry:

`+-o IOUserServer(com.myinc.mydriver ... registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0ms), retain 13`

I unplug the device and do another `ioreg` and I get the same but with retain 9.

If I plug my device, then another `ioreg` now shows 2 entries (the previous one and a new one).

Is this normal? Why is the previous one still active?

In my dext I check that my Stop and free functions are called and I cannot think of anything I have missed.

Can someone please explain this to me or point me toward what I may have forgotten to do? Does retain 9 have anything to do with what I do in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem and will leave an answer here in case it helps someone else...

I obtained my `IOUSBHostInterface` object using `CopyInterface()` (from `IOUSBHostDevice`).
Then on this object I called `Open()`.

In my `Stop()` implementation I called `Close()` on my interface object but I forgot to call `release`.

Now when I disconnect my device, once all my `free()` functions are called, in the console I get the message "no service left, exiting".

Comment: I get `<private>`, how come you can see "no service left, exiting"?

Comment: See if this helps:

https://superuser.com/questions/1311578/in-console-app-how-can-i-reveal-to-what-private-tags-are-actually-referring